Standardization of summary statistic of group-linked values
Assume that you measure a summary statistic (e.g., arithmetic mean) in measurement windows of a fixed size along a long sequence of values and that these values are grouped into regions belonging to one of two classes (A and ¬A):
Values: 21  22  14  89  76  45  33  14  52  61  
Group: |A   A   A  |¬A  ¬A  ¬A  ¬A  ¬A  ¬A |A   
Stat.: | 21.5  | 51.5  | 60.5  | 23.5  | 56.5  |

If you wanted to test if the values in regions of group A are statistically different from the values in regions of group ¬A, it would not be correct to compare the summary statistic unadjusted:
 A = 21.5 + (51.5/2) + (56.5/2) = 75.5
¬A = (51.5/2) + 60.5 + 23.5 + (56.5/2) = 138

Instead, one would need to standardize the values by group length. What is the mathematically preferred form of standardizing the values in such a calculation?
For example, is it sufficient to merely subdivide the summary statistics by the actual number of comparisons:
A = 75.5/4 = 18.875
¬A = 138/6 = 23


Edit 1: As per a commenter's request, here is an alternative display of the example:
Values: 21  22  14  89  76  45  33  14  52  61  
x_bar: | 21.5  | 51.5  | 60.5  | 23.5  | 56.5  |
Group: | A  A  | A  ¬A |¬A  ¬A |¬A  ¬A |¬A  A  | 


I cannot understand your table because the columns do not align. Could you please explain how to read it and the basis of the subsequent calculations?  Then, please tell us what you intend by "statistically different" and "standardizing ... by group length" (which apparently does not simply mean "averaging").

@whuber As you requested, I have added a table version where the columns align (see Edit 1). My aim is to compare the mean of A to the mean of ¬A after standardizing for the different population sizes (i.e., popsize(A) = 4, popsize(¬A)=6). The mere division displayed in my example seems too simple a standardization, I think.

I thought I understood until you wrote "standardizing for the different population sizes."  I have no idea what that might mean.  Could you explain?
